# Pause YouTube video on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm creating a function which inserts an YouTube iframe when user hovers on a div an then `when the user leaves div the video is paused.` Everythings works fine but video is not paused when user leaves div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/20/

Any ideas? Thank You!

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        player = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'), {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'wJnnT1SGEsc',
            playerVars: {
            wmode: "transparent",
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3 //anottations
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }


    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is probably not ready - as per [the youtube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you need to implement the onYoutubeIframeAPIReady function.

Try this instead:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        player = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'), {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'wJnnT1SGEsc',
            playerVars: {
            wmode: "transparent",
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3 //anottations
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }


    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
});
}
```

Note that this is just an educated guess, but you can provide a jsfiddle if you want something more concrete.

EDIT: [This works for the first time](http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/21/).

The reason it does not work afterwards is because there is no longer a mouseleave- since there is no longer a mouseenter - the iframe is completely covering the previous div and therefore you never enter it, so you cant leave it.

You want to use mouseout for this.

Comment: Thanks, what about multiple divs? I need it to work with more than one @Etai